# How does initialization of neural networks affect convergence?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

If a neural network is initialized with small random weights and run for a very large number of iterations (20k or more), cqn the final accuracy range (difference of order of magnitude 10e-4 is okay) differ much for a rerun of same model?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CJM Err are you sure? "Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people interested in *conceptual questions about life and challenges in a world where "cognitive" functions can be mimicked in purely digital environment.*"... Doesn't sound like this question would be a good fit there.

Comment: @rlanvin Yeah, pretty sure this is a question about Neural Networks, an area within the field of AI, and not a programming problem. Looks like others agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can differ. It will usually not be the case, but in theory it can, and sometimes it does. It's due to the randomness in the initialization and in the feeding order during training, which can both lead the optimization to end up in a different local minimum of your cost function each time. This is why researchers developed initialization techniques that are supposed to be better than others, such as [Xavier initialisation](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/110998971763/an-explanation-of-xavier-initialization).

It's good practice, if you have the time, to train several times, just to see if your results are very different between the runs, or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!  The link you added was a great read!